# Disappearing Lines?

Tags: errors

I have a strange (and serious) problem.  For some reason, text that is showing up in the pdf of my file (I'm using TeXworks) ... is no longer showing up in the file itself.  And when I go to the line where it should be, the program crashes.  Clicking above and below those lines clearly shows that lines are just missing (as in, it goes from line 300 to 400 over a difference of 10 lines).

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Your problem look like an editor problem to me. Can you view your source file with a different program?

Answer (score 1):

I think your file might be corrupted.  Please try to open it with some other programs (such as notepad++) to see if everything is still there.

If so, save it and try to run it elsewhere (e.g., a computer on your campus) and see if you still have the problem.

I don't think this is a "known problem" in TeXworks... looks more like a personal issue

Comment: FWIW, I occasionally get a similar crash in TeXWorks, but I've never been able to pin it down. I *suspect* it's related either to large pastes, or to fast scrolling with PgDn or down-arrow.